# convert data wide to long with make sequential date in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data frame with date like below :

```
id  start_date  end_date     product supply_per_day 
1   2020-03-01  2020-03-01      A            10
1   2020-03-01  2020-03-01      B            10
1   2020-03-01  2020-03-02      A             5
2   2020-02-28  2020-03-02      A            10
2   2020-03-01  2020-03-03      B             4
2   2020-03-02  2020-03-05      A             5
```

I want make this data wide to long like :

```
id        date  product  supply_per_day 
1   2020-03-01      A           10
1   2020-03-01      B           10
1   2020-03-01      A            5
1   2020-03-02      A            5
2   2020-02-28      A           10
2   2020-03-01      A           10
2   2020-03-02      A           10
2   2020-03-01      B            4
2   2020-03-02      B            4
2   2020-03-03      B            4
2   2020-03-02      B            5
2   2020-03-03      B            5
2   2020-03-04      B            5
2   2020-03-05      B            5
```

give me some idea please

Comment: You have tagged 4 different RDBMS, which one are you using?

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used. (Note that the same query will probably not work with all of the tagged products.)

Comment: You say a data frame.  Does that mean, you are using pandas?  You tagged SQL. Does that mean, you are looking for a SQL query?  A little more clarification would help.

Comment: @KateYoak postgresql

Comment: @MT0 postgresql

Comment: sorry all I didn't think about RDBMS I looking for postgresql query

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle 12c and later, you can use:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       d.dt,
       t.product,
       t.supply_per_day
FROM   table_name t
       OUTER APPLY(
         SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1 AS dt
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= end_date
       ) d
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, start_date, end_date, product, supply_per_day ) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-03-01', DATE '2020-03-01', 'A', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-03-01', DATE '2020-03-01', 'B', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-03-01', DATE '2020-03-02', 'A',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-02-28', DATE '2020-03-02', 'A', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-03-01', DATE '2020-03-03', 'B',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-03-02', DATE '2020-03-05', 'A',  5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | DT | PRODUCT | SUPPLY_PER_DAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | A | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | B | 10 |
| 1 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | A | 5 |
| 1 | 2020-03-02 00:00:00 | A | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-02-28 00:00:00 | A | 10 |
| 2 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00 | A | 10 |
| 2 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | A | 10 |
| 2 | 2020-03-02 00:00:00 | A | 10 |
| 2 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00 | B | 4 |
| 2 | 2020-03-02 00:00:00 | B | 4 |
| 2 | 2020-03-03 00:00:00 | B | 4 |
| 2 | 2020-03-02 00:00:00 | A | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-03-03 00:00:00 | A | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-03-04 00:00:00 | A | 5 |
| 2 | 2020-03-05 00:00:00 | A | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=14115a5be0faed7d1feaea6c885edbc4)*

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can use `generate_series()` for this:

```
select t.id, g.day::date as date, t.product, t.supply_per_day
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(t.start_date, t.end_date, interval '1 day') as g(day)
order by t.id, g.day
```